# How to re-encrypt .password-store using new gpg key

Tags: passwords, gnupg

I am using [pass](https://www.passwordstore.org) to manage my passwords. It uses [my GPG key](https://pgp.mit.edu/pks/lookup?search=kris+leech&op=index) to encrypt.

My key recently expired and I created a new one.

`pass` will no longer create new passwords since my old key expired.

I can decrypt existing passwords. It uses the old ID `3D1B47D3` as when decrypting I see `gpg: Note: secret key 3D1B47D3 expired at Sun 02 Jul 2017 16:36:45 BST`.

`3D1B47D3` is my old key id, `1F7CCC88` is my new key ID.

Therefore I need to re-encrypt `~/.password-store` using my new key. The docs say using  `pass init 1F7CCC88` should do so.

However I get the error:

```
gpg: [stdin]: encryption failed: Unusable public key
gpg: Note: secret key 3D1B47D3 expired at Sun 02 Jul 2017 16:36:45 BST`.
```

The error is repeated for every password.

`~/.password-store/.gpg-id` contains my new key ID since running `init`.

I can encrypt files manually using `gpg --encrypt filename` using my new key.

Note my keys and sub-keys all have an expire date in the future.

```
pub   4096R/1F7CCC88 2016-07-02 [expires: 2018-07-28]
uid                  Kris Leech <kris.leech@gmail.com>
sub   4096R/3D1B47D3 2016-07-02 [expires: 2018-07-28]
sub   2048R/E77481E9 2016-07-28 [expires: 2018-07-28]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gpg --encrypt fails](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/53290/gpg-encrypt-fails)

Comment: I looked at this question already, their issue was that they didn't change the expire for the sub-keys too. But as far as I can see this isn't my issue. I can encrypt/decrypt outside of `pass` using my new key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like pass is using gpg2, you created the keys using gpg, and there is something not supported in gpg2 (md5 deprecated?).

e.g. decrypting with gpg works:

```
$ gpg -d --quiet secret.gpg 

You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
user: "bot three (third bot) <bot3@blah.com>"
2048-bit RSA key, ID 2A8EA0F6, created 2017-08-24 (main key ID 2003591B)

something much longer then blah
```

and with gpg2 doesn't:

```
$ gpg2 -d --quiet secret.gpg 
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
```

Renaming gpg2 forces pass to use gpg:

```
# mv /usr/bin/gpg2 /usr/bin/gpg2-css
$ pass show test/secret
something much longer then blah
```

What you can do is:

1. Rename gpg2.
2. Create a gpg2 key.
3. Re-init the password store using the new gpg2 generated key to re-encrypt.
4. Rename gpg2 back to gpg2.

Should work again at this point. From here, use gpg2, not gpg.

hth.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the answer I accepted I wanted to post another option. You can just import your existing key in to gpg2.

```
gpg --list-keys
gpg --export [ID] > public.key
gpg --export-secret-key [ID] > private.key
gpg2 --import public.key
gpg2 --import private.key
rm public.key private.key
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm late to the party but I found a solution.

I must say that none of this solutions worked for me and I have multiple folders inside `~/.password-store` with dozens of keys which means i can't avoid the folder issue.

What worked for me is:

```
$ cp -r ~/.password-store ~/.password-store.backup
$ cd ~/.password-store
$ pass init <new-gpg-key-hash>
Password store initialized for <new-gpg-key-hash>
folder1/pass1: reencrypting to <new-gpg-key-hash> 
gpg: Note: secret key <old-gpg-key-hash> expired at Tue XX Jul 2021 XX:YY:ZZ AM EDT
folder2/pass1: reencrypting to <new-gpg-key-hash> 
gpg: Note: secret key <old-gpg-key-hash> expired at Tue XX Jul 2021 XX:YY:ZZ AM EDT
...
```

You can verify it worked by copying a pass and generating a new pass (causing the can't verify authenticity of some other public key which turns out was strange side effect):

```
pass -c folder1/pass1
pass generate test/test
```

This did work. **If something is wrong you can simply:**

```
mv ~/.password-store.backup ~/.password-store
```

Hope it helps someone else! cheers

Answer (score 1):

`pass init *gpg-id*` in an existing password-store directory will reencrypt the entire store to *gpg-id*.

Per [`pass` manfiles](https://git.zx2c4.com/password-store/about/):

> If the specified gpg-id is different from the key used in any existing files, these files will be reencrypted to use the new id.